# Hyper-V release mouse same keys as screen rotation

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2

The shortcut to release the mouse capture in Hyper-V in 2008 R2 is the same key combination as rotating the screen.  When I press this combination, the screen rotates and the mouse is still not released.

Is there same way to change one or the other key combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> and it'll trigger mouse release, but not rotate the screen and you don't have to change configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  That's an unfortunate collision.  Clearly the people who do the TabletPC user interface don't use Hyper-V much, and vice versa.  You can change the TabletPC keys under the tablet part of the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer you can also change the key combination for Hyper-V.

You will find this under Server Manager > Hyper-V Manager > , Hyper-V Settings from the action plane...

[sample pic](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?972101c3d5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works on all OSes, but either Windows keys (Left or right) releases the mouse when VM is Android 4.3, which has no integration.